# Change order of fields in theme.json?

Tags: shopware6

Is there a way to change the order of the blocks/fields for a custom theme configuration?

No matter how I rearrange the theme.json file, nothing seems to change in the configuration page in admin.

Not possible?

Shopware 6.5

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the order of the fields can be defined in the config fields. You can add [`order`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/b1a1c2e4d4abc80f7d1e9469725e1801cc1462c5/src/Storefront/Resources/theme.json#L83) parameter to the config field.

After that run `bin/console theme:refresh` command in order to changes reflected in the theme in the admin.

Comment: Thanks. But I can not get that working. It seems totally random in what order the fields are (even with "order" parameter. I have also added two new blocks: One have been placed on top and one at the end...?

Comment: I'm not sure if the order of the blocks can be changed or not. Only the config fields' order can be changed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - it seems like the positions are fixed and whenever you override a variable, shopware tries to resolve that order with no regards to the order.